# Thickbox seems to have just stopped loading images, although iFrame still works

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I can't figure this one out!

Thickbox seems to have stopped loading images in it's default lightbox mode - I've made no changes and the clients just reported it.
Weird thing is the iFrame version works fine.

I'm seeing no errors, but using Tamper Data through Firefox there's no attempt to call the image either.
Example page is here: http://www.lens-wear.co.uk/details.php?AID=9&TID=0&BID=5&PID=645

If you click an image top right then they don't load, but if you click 'Add' it brings up the order wizard via Thickbox in an iFrame as expected.

I'm normally pretty good with this sort of thing, but with no error and no http traffic I can't work it out.
I guess I could just fix it by moving across to Shadowbox.

Yours,
Chris

Comment: Hmm, really really odd. I just went through everything I could think of and found nothing. My only hunch is that this may be a naming/variable conflict between the various Javascripts you use. Can you try loading the page with Thickbox only?

Comment: Yep, I'm going to have to.  Step through each routine until I find the answer.

Comment: I've removed all but jQuery and Thickbox. It still demonstrates the same problem unless I remove the Gallery feature via rel.
Even loading jQuery via Google doesn't fix it (in case my local version is corrupt!)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `rel` attribute from the `<a>` tag did the trick for me.

Comment: Hi Alex, it does then work but you lose the slideshow aspect where it links each image to the next.
It's a good fix for the minute though, thanks :)